# Is there any mistake in this sentence below?

Tags: grammar, present-simple

> The wealthy matron is so proud of her valuable antique vase **that** she **decides** to have her bedroom painted the same colours as the vase .

As far as l know we should use "such that" not "so that", am I wrong?

Plus I have never seen the usage of the verb "decide" with present tense?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct.

Both "such that" and "so that" are used in English. But here we actually have ".. so proud..." and then later a "that" clause.  This type of structure is quite common

> I was so happy that I danced on the table.
>
> I was so happy with my exam result that I danced on the table.

The verb "decide" can have its normal present tense. Here it seems to be commentary: a narrator is describing a scene as it happens, this is one of the standard uses of the simple present. Narration or commentary doesn't often happen in conversation, but it is a standard technique in fiction writing and sports reporting.

> The goalkeeper kicks the ball. It lands at Messi's feet. He dribbles it forwards and shoots. It's a goal!

Comment: Dont we use so /that with adj  or adverb and such/that with adj+noun ? Valuable  (adj) and vase (noun) arent that?

Comment: We use "so" when we mean "so".  In this case it is modifying the adjective "proud" so by your rule, we should use "so".

Comment: Thank you so much James